# Mssql grouping by a column and joining it with the amount of occurances there exist in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, let's say we have `My_column` which has 2 occurrances of `b_value`, 3 occurances of `a_value` and 1 occurrance of `c_value`, like this:

```
b_value
b_value
a_value
a_value
a_value
c_value
```

What I'd like to do is use `GROUP BY` on the values and then count the number of occurences and set them up accordingly, like this:

```
b_value | 2
a_value | 3
c_value | 1
```

I don't even know where to start. I'vee been fuzzing around in management studio, but no luck thus far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `group by` clause and `count` function as below

```
select My_column, count(1) as cnt
from my_table
group by My_column
```

[**Sql Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c9ab/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`COUNT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) function for that grouping by `My_Column`:

```
SELECT My_Column, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY My_Column
```

#### Have a look at [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f16b0/1)